# Point halving formula for Koblitz curve over prime field

Tags: elliptic-curves, secp256k1

Consider a Koblitz elliptic curve over a prime field $\mathbb F_p$, with equation $y^2=x^3+b$, prime order $n$ close to (but different from) $p$. This includes secp256k1, secp224k1, secp192k1, secp160k1, and for a toy example $p=241,b=13,n=211$.

Given $(x_P,y_P)$ for $P$ on the curve, classic point doubling formula allows to compute coordinates $(x_Q,y_Q)$ for $Q=[2]P$.

What are explicit formula or algorithm to compute $(x_P,y_P)$ from $(x_Q,y_Q)$, faster than the obvious point multiplication $P=[(n+1)/2]Q$ ?

---

This is a special case of [Elliptic Curve - Divide by 2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55069/elliptic-curve-divide-by-2), which has no satisfactory answer with explicit formula.

Comment: This [paper from Feb '23](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.00568.pdf) (paying particular attention to example 2) should give formulae which only require the extraction of square roots and the usual arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 2):

Point halving in Secp256k1 - the others are similar.

Let $P = [\frac a 2]G$  i.e. we have $[2]P = [a]G = Q$. In words, $P$ is the halfpoint of $Q$.

Let $P = (p_x,q_x)$ and $Q = (q_x,q_x)$

We may expect that it has two solutions $$P =\big[\frac{a}{2}\big]G =\big[\frac{a + q}{2}\big] G \left(= \big[\frac{a}{2}\big] G + \big[\frac{ q}{2}\big] G \right), $$ however, the base point $G$ of the Bitcoin curve has odd order;

```
int("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141", 16)
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
```

Therefore, if there exists half of a point then it is [unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1736008/338051).

1. The derivative of the equation $y^2 = x^3 + 7$

$\lambda = \dfrac{3x^{2}}   
    {2(x^{3}  + 7)^{1/2}} \tag{1} \label{r1}$

2. Write down the equation for the tangent line to $E$ at G:

$$y-p_y = \lambda(x-p_x) => y = \lambda(x - p_x) + p_y \tag{2}$$

3. Write the equation for the intersection of the tangent line with E:

$$y^{2} = (\lambda(x - p_x) + p_y)^{2} = x^{3} + 7 \tag{3}\label{r3}$$

4. Write down $\lambda$ in terms of $p_x$:

   If we extend the equation \ref{r3}, we will get a monic cubic polynomial, so the coefficient of $x^2$ will be minus the sum of the roots ([Vieta's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) ($-b/a$)), and the leading coefficient is 1.

   \begin{align}
   x^{3} + 7 & = (\lambda (x - p_x) + p_y)^{2}  \\
   x^{3} + 7 & = \lambda^2 (x - p_x)^2 + 2 \lambda (x - p_x) p_y + p_y^{2} \\
   x^{3} + 7 & = \lambda^2 (x^2 - 2 x p_x + p_x^2) + 2 \lambda x p_y - 2 \lambda p_x p_y + p_y^{2} \\
   0 &= x^{3} + 7  - \lambda^2 (x^2 - 2 x p_x + p_x^2) - 2 \lambda x p_y + 2 \lambda p_x p_y - p_y \\
   0 &= x^{3} \color{red}{- \lambda^2 x^2} + \lambda^2 2 x p_x - \lambda^2 p_x^2 - 2 \lambda x p_y + 2 \lambda p_x p_y - p_y^{2} + 7\\
   0 &= x^{3} \color{red}{- \lambda^2 x^2} + (\lambda^2 2 p_x - 2 \lambda p_y)x + (- \lambda^2 p_x^2 + 2 \lambda p_x p_y - p_y^{2} + 7)\\
   \end{align}

   as we can see the term for $x^2$ is $- \lambda^2$. Since the roots are the intersection point then $p_x$ will be a double point and $q_x$ will be a single point, by Vieata's formula $$\lambda^2 = 2 p_x + q_x  \label{r4}\tag{4}$$
5. Form equation using equation \ref{r4} and and replacing $x$ with $p_x$ in the equation \ref{r1};

   $$\lambda^{2} = 2p_x + q_x  =  \frac{9p_x^{\,4}}{4(p_x^{\,3}  + 7)} \tag{5} \label{r5}$$

   Simplify this equation and move everything over to the left-hand side will yield $$ (2p_x + q_x)(4(p_x^{\,3}  + 7))  =  9p_x^{\,4}\\ -p_x^4 + 4 p_x^3 q_x + 56 p_x + 28 q_x= 0$$

a quartic polynomial in $p_x$. The roots of this polynomial are the x-coordinates of the half points of $G$. We are in the odd case, the factors of the quartic polynomial will be a linear equation and an irreducible resolvent cubic.

---

The validation with SageMath

```
#Secp256K1 prime
p = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f
#Secp256K1 order
q =  115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
#One of the roots
t = 82764486716702815285605477501188164702466527314352175978120539775788537185277
print("Expected root ", t)


#define ring of polynomials
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(p),'x')

# x-coordinate of Q where Q = [2]P
qx =  Integer(84538659774007663836420160802839342215744092791779235474817172502887599548487)


#From equation (5)
g = (2 *x + qx)*(4*(x^3+7)) - (3*x^2)^2

gRoots = g.roots()

print("The roots of quartic = ", gRoots)

gEvalAt_t = ((2 *t + qx)*(4*(t^3+7)) - (3*t^2)^2 ) % p

print( "gg(t) =", gEvalAt_t)
```

Outputs

```
Expected root  82764486716702815285605477501188164702466527314352175978120539775788537185277
The roots of quartic =  [(82764486716702815285605477501188164702466527314352175978120539775788537185277, 1)]
gg(t) = 0
```

Try, online on [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=zqmllo)

Note that this is a single test.

Comment: For prime curves, all points can be generator, so it is not matter which one we choose and I did not used the value of the base point. Because we combined the curve and the tangent line, so there is expected one linear solution.

Comment: I admit I do not know how to solve $-p_x^{\,4}+4p_x^{\,3}q_x+56p_x+28q_x=0$ for $p_x$. Also, I see no reason it has a single solution, so we need a strategy to select the right $p_x$, and also to select $p_y$. Update (Nov 8): the code shows there is indeed a single solution. My intuition was bad!

Comment: @fgrieu My calculations are per this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.4379.pdf). My formulas do not verify yet. I'm reviewing all, from time to time. Quartic roots may be hard to use, however, I've used a library for the [ray-tracing for the torus](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87545/18298). I'm considering that the paper and my calculation are not correct. I'll look deeper. In the end, we can talk about performance about directly using scalar vs this.

Comment: @fgrieu Ok. I've validated the formulas with SageMath. More explanation will come later.